# how to do picker to use only one line to show the selected value?

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms

I am working with xamarin.forms and I am using a picker.
But, depend of the selected value, on android it breaks the line...But I need it always use only one line. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Have you read this https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry/

Comment: yes, I have.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom renderer for the `Picker` as the comment suggested, and then in your renderer, you can for example code like this:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyPicker), typeof(MyPickerRenderer))]

namespace NameSpace.Droid
{
    public class MyPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
    {
        private bool isShown;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var et = this.Control as EditText;
                et.SetSingleLine(true);
            }
        }

    }
}
```